# How to close an excel file using terminal or python

Tags: mac, terminal, microsoft-excel-2011

I am using [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html) to create an Excel file using a Python script.

When I re-run the script to update the file with new information, which I need to do often, I have to manually close the Excel file and reopen it to look at the new version of the spreadsheet.

Is there a way to automate this process:  Close the excel file (not the application) using a terminal command and then re-open it.

I know how to open it, but don't know how to close a file.

Comment: i'm not sure if this is relevant but maybe a VBA macro is ok for you and maybe it can be called from the command line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050505/way-to-run-excel-macros-from-command-line-or-batch-file

Comment: Please see the edits. I have excel. That is what I am using currently to look at the file. @barlop I am on Mac OSX. I am not sure whether the link you gave would work for that. Sorry, forgot to include that information above.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [a post over on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337595/python-win32-com-closing-excel-workbook), the answer was that the Workbook COM contains within it a Close() method. The code snippet from the mentioned post:

```
xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('New Workbook.xlsx')
# do some stuff
wb.Close(True) # save the workbook
```

Here's the necessary syntax rules [from the Microsoft site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff838613.aspx):

```
expression .Close(SaveChanges, Filename, RouteWorkbook)
expression A variable that represents a Workbook object.
```

When it comes to OSX, apparently you need to use [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/)

With some looking, I'm not overly familiar with appscript, you should be able to get to do what you are looking for by doing something like:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
   close workbook 1 saving no
end tell
```

Finally, here is the documentation for the appscript package for Python:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appscript

Comment: I think this solution is for Windows. I am using Excel on Mac. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi @user37473 , I've made an update to include some Mac specific information.

Answer (score 0):

In Python (3.6) this works for me

```
import os

os.system(f'''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "Microsoft Excel" to close (every window whose name is "title-of-window")' ''')
```